# Generalization of Karamata’s theorem to integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, inequality

Karamata's theorem states the following: let $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function, $x_1\ge x_2\ge \cdots \ge x_n$ and $y_1\ge \cdots \ge y_n$ be reals such that $\sum\limits_{j=1}^n x_j=\sum\limits_{j=1}^n y_j$ and $\sum\limits_{j=1}^k x_j \ge \sum\limits_{j=1}^k y_j$ for all $k\in \{1,\cdots,n\}$. Then

$\sum\limits_{j=1}^n f(x_j) \ge \sum\limits_{j=1}^n f(y_j)$.

I am wondering if the following are true:

1.1 Let $a,b: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be decreasing functions and $f$ be a convex function such that $f(a(x))$ is Riemann integrable.

If $\int_0^1 a(x) dx = \int_0^1 b(x) dx$ and $\int_0^k a(x) dx \ge \int_0^k b(x) dx$ for all $0\le k\le 1$, then $$\int_0^1 f(a(x)) dx \ge \int_0^1 f(b(x)) dx$$

1.2 have riemann integrable changed to generally integrable (can be Lesbegue Integrable for example)

1.3 $a$ is decreasing but $b$ is not necessarily decreasing. All other conditions hold (for simplicity we will assume $f\circ a, f\circ b$ are riemann integrable.

Thank you for your interest!

Comment: Small remark: in your exposition of Karamata's theorem, the inequality between summations of $f(x_j)$ and $f(y_j)$ cannot be strict, because nothing prevents the $x_j$ from being equal to the $y_j$.

Comment: what would $k$ refer to in the continuous setting?

Comment: You may search some related results. For example, An Integral Inequality
Author(s): Ky Fan and G. G. Lorentz
Reviewed work(s):
Source: The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 61, No. 9 (Nov., 1954), pp. 626-631.